# Angular data inaccessible outside subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an issue about Angular 2 (sorry about my english that is not good enough...).

I would like to manipulate a component variable from an other component. The problem is this component variable is undefined outside the **subscribe** function whereas it is clearly viewable inside. So, I can't expect to access this variable without this component.

Here is my service **MailRepertoryService** :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class MailRepertoryService {

      constructor(private http: Http) { }

      getMailsRepertory() {
        return this.http
          .get('data/dossiers.json')
          .map(res => res.json());
      }

      getMailsRepertoryFields() {
        return this.http
          .get('data/champs.json')
          .map(res => res.json())
      }

    }
```

And here is my **AppComponent** :

```
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { MailRepertoryService } from './services/mail.repertory.service';
    import { Box, Field, Mail } from './types/mailbox.type';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {

      private title = 'Em Ta Box';
      boxRepertory: Box[];
      mailRepertory: Box;
      fields: Field[];
      private errors: string;

      constructor(private mailRepertoryService: MailRepertoryService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.mailRepertoryService.getMailsRepertory().subscribe(
          (mailRepertories: Box[]) => {
            this.boxRepertory = mailRepertories;
            console.log(this.boxRepertory); // visible object
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.errors = error;
          }
        );
        this.mailRepertoryService.getMailsRepertoryFields().subscribe(
          data => this.fields = data,
          error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.errors = error;
          }
        );
        console.log(this.boxRepertory); // undefined
      }

    }
```

How can I access to **this.boxRepertory** variable outside the subscribe ?

With Thanks.

Comment: Do what you need to inside the subscribe callback. You can't work something that hasn't been  delivered yet

Comment: Is there any alternative ? I mean abandoning the use of 'rxjs'...

Comment: No...that is simply how asynchronous operations work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: So, there is a synchronous alternative ?

Comment: Will never get very far in angular apps , or any modern web apps thinking like that. Have to learn to code using asynchronous operations. You could simply call a function in the subscribe and pass the data to that function

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Import Observable from rxjs to use flatMap

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mailRepertoryService.getMailsRepertory().flatMap(
      (mailRepertories: Box[]) => {
        this.boxRepertory = mailRepertories;
        console.log(this.boxRepertory); // visible object
        return this.mailRepertoryService.getMailsRepertoryFields();
 }).subscribe(
      data => this.fields = data,
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        this.errors = error;
      }, 
      () => {
        console.log(this.boxRepertory);
      });
   }
```